# Why can't I host my hidden service?

Tags: configuration, web-hosting

I am using Ubuntu eoan. Here is what I did:

- Uncommented `#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/` and `#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80` in `/etc/tor/torrc`
- Restarted `tor` service by using `sudo service tor restart`
- Ran `sudo nano /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hostname`

After I ran `sudo nano /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hostname`, nano didn't show any text. I also tried this with `gedit`, and the output was the same. So I opened file explorer and went to `/var/lib/tor`, and the directory was empty. What did I do wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Could you look into `/var/log/tor/` if there are any files (`log`, `notices.log`, etc.)? If so, please open it. Are there any lines which start with `WARN`? Please edit your question and copy them into the question. They can help to find the issue.

Comment: @JensKubieziel I checked and the directory is empty, but it is a directory

Comment: Please run `sudo journalctl -ef _SYSTEMD_UNIT=tor@default.service` and restart Tor (`sudo systemctl restart tor`). Do you see error messages?